# Sound Sensor RGB LED coding

Tags: led, msp430, code-composer

So we connected a sound sensor to our board to light up our LED light when sound is heard, it kinda works but there some hiccups.

We tried messing with the code for a while but no matter what we do the senor will only react to loud even when we put in a threshold. If you see in the picture, it it only displaying ***"loud"*** noise to the display and cant seem be able to go to the other condition we set in our threshold. We configure the sensor with our screw driver but nothing seem to work. Our code is below & before we continue on, we wanted to know if there a problem with it that can fix out the issue,thanks you

ALSO the sound sensor is a "ko9A01"
PS: we use "energia" to code this.

[image]

[image]

```
#include <msp430.h>
#include <Wire.h>

int soundsensor = 2;
int led = 3;                

void setup() 
{ 
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Begin Test");
  pinMode(soundsensor,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led,OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{


int sensorValue = digitalRead(soundsensor);
Serial.println(sensorValue);
delay(250); 

if (sensorValue == 1) 
{
  Serial.print("LOUD");
  digitalWrite(led,HIGH);

 }
else
{
  Serial.print("QUIET");
  digitalWrite(led,LOW);

}

}
```

EDIT: NOW With the help of Brydon we change the output to input and change it to this we change it to this and now we get this new error voi

```
void setup() 
{ 
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Begin Testing");
  pinMode(soundsensor,INPUT);
}
```

and it only show 
"begin test":

0 and wont move from there

Answer (score 1):

You have the sound sensor configured as an `OUTPUT` in the setup.

I assume you want it to be an input? That would be the case if you're reading values from it.

I can't tell what sensor you have - but with more information on the sensor, we can read the documentation and help you configure the inputs appropriately (ie a threshold)

Comment: my sound sensor is a ko9A01

Comment: we change it to this and now we get this new error

void setup() 
{ 
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Begin Testing");
  pinMode(soundsensor,INPUT);
}

and it only show "begin test": 0 and wont move from there :(